# Listar 2 Tabelas em Um objeto Orientado

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Estou com um trabalho acadêmico.
e não estou listar os dados do BD, ou seja esta dando o erro java.lang.NullPointerException  Pesquisei algo semelhante achei , vi uns exemplos porem a forma que utilizam e criando os mesmo atributos dentro da propria classe Produtos, porem nao posso utilizar dessa forma

Minhas Classes

Marca.java

```
public class Marca {

private long id;
private String nome;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

}

Produto.Class

```
public class Produto {

private int id;
private String nome;
private double preco;
private Marca marca;

public Produto(String nome, Marca marca) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.marca = marca;
}

public Produto() {
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Marca getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(Marca marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}
```

}

ProdutoDAO

```
 public List<Produto> consultarTodos() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Connection con = Conexao.getConnection();
    List<Produto> todosProdutos = new ArrayList<>();
    try (
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT a.nome,b.idProdutos,b.nomeProdutos FROM marca  as A , produtos  as B where a.id = b.idmarca")) {

        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

            while (rs.next()) {
                Produto p = new Produto();
                p.setId(rs.getInt("idProdutos"));
                p.getMarca().setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                todosProdutos.add(p);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
            // ATENÇÃO: Comer exceções só dando um System.out.println nelas é uma má prática de programação!
        }
        return todosProdutos;

    }
}
```

Por fim a JSP

```
       <c:forEach var="prod" items="${produtos}" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                <ul class="list-group">

                    <th><li class="list-group-item">${prod.nome}</li></th>
                    <th><li class="list-group-item">${prod.marca.nome}</li></th>
                </ul>

                <th><td><input type="button" value="Atualizar" onclick="javascript: setIDAtualizar(${prod.id});"></td></th>
                <th><td><input type="button" value="Excluir" onclick="javascript: setIDExclusao(${prod.id});"></td></th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </form>
        </thead>
    </c:forEach>
```

E a servlet

```
    ProdutoDAO dao = new ProdutoDAO();

    List<Produto> produto = null;
    try {
        produto = dao.consultarTodos();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BuscarProdutosController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BuscarProdutosController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    request.setAttribute("produtos", produto);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Controle/buscar/listaProdutos.jsp").forward(request, response);

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema parece ser na forma em que está *setando* o valor para o seu objeto marca no seu `Produto p`. Quando você dá um `p.getMarca().setNome(rs.getString("nome"))`, o objeto marca está `nulo`, seria necessário **inicializar o mesmo primeiro** e depois setar o nome.

Algo muito semelhante ao que você fez no seu produto, seria:

```
p.setMarca(new Marca());
p.getMarca.setNome(rs.getString(1)); 
//nesse caso estou utilizando um índice para referência
```

Veja esse [exemplo](https://github.com/ricardoalvim-edu/TreinamentoJavaFX/blob/master/AcademicoFx/src/main/java/br/com/fema/academicofx/dao/AlunoDAO.java) de utilização do `JDBC` para obtenção de uma lista de objetos do banco de dados e para fazer um vinculo com os objetos relacionais:

Comment: Funcionou, vou testar aqui. Muito Obrigado